# Mostra itens conforme seleção de um select (HTML)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Boa tarde!

Possuo um banco de dados com duas tabelas, produtos e cardápios, as duas tabelas estão indexadas através do campo CdCardapio. Criei um elemento html select que contém todos os cardápios cadastrados, preciso que quando selecionado, por exemplo, o cardápio "Bebidas", somente os produtos que CdCardapio for igual ao selecionado sejam listados. 
Porém, preciso que isto aconteça sem atualizar a página, aí que está o problema, ainda não aprendi trabalhar muito bem com jQuery e Ajax, alguém pode me ajudar?

Já possuo o código que lista os cardápios existentes:

```
            <select class="form-control" id="cardapio" name="CdCardapio">
            <option value=""> Selecione um Cardápio </option>       
            <?php foreach($cardapios as $cardapio) : ?>
                <option class="cardapio" value="<?=$cardapio['CdCardapio']?>">
                               <?=$cardapio['nomeCardapio']?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>
```

Agora preciso que conforme for o cardápio selecionado, sejam listados os produtos pertencentes a ele na tabela abaixo, a qual, agora, estou listando todos os produtos, vejam:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered">
         <tr class="active">
             <td>
                 <b>Produto</b>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <b>Valor</b>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <b>Quantidade</b>  
             </td>
         </tr>
         <?php
           $produtos = listaProdutos($conexao);
           foreach($produtos as $produto) :
         ?>

        <tr class="produto">
            <td hidden><?=$produto['CdProduto'] ?></td> 
            <td hidden><?=$produto['CdCardapio'] ?></td>        
            <td><?=$produto['nomeProduto'] ?></td>
            <td><div class="valor"><?=$produto['valorProduto']?></div></td>
            <td>
                <input class="quantidade" type="number" value="0" size="1" maxlength="2" max="10" min="0" step="0">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php
             endforeach;
        ?>
    </table>
```

Função listaProdutos:

```
function listaProdutos($conexao) {
     $produtos = array ();
     $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select p.*, c.nomeCardapio 
                                          from cardapios c, produtos p
                                          where c.CdCardapio = p.CdCardapio");
     while($produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
                  array_push($produtos, $produto);
                  }
                  return $produtos;
     }
```

Creio que agora ficou mais claro, desculpem o transtorno!!

Comment: Você tentou alguma coisa? Se sim, poste seu código com o problema específico. Se não teríamos que criar a rotina toda do zero.

Comment: A solução postada dá pra você adaptar, Estado => Cardápio / Cidade => Produtos...

Comment: Mas porque não ajusta conforme eu te mostrei?

Comment: Quando você postou eu estava editando a minha pergunta! 
Vou ajustar assim que estiver pronto eu posto aqui.
Valeu André!

Comment: Ok, qualquer coisa se não conseguir, poste o que conseguiu ajustar e a gente analisa aqui e te ajuda a concluir. Valeu! ;)

Comment: Ok, tenho uma dúvida, no meu caso preciso mostrar os dados em uma tabela, não em um select, para ser específico são dois campos do banco de dados que preciso carregar nesta tabela. Para carregar no select, fiz uns exemplos aqui e deu certo, mas não sei como poderia fazer na tabela.

Comment: Também dá pra fazer, conseguiu ajustar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Olá @Fred poderia tentar de outra forma utilizando somente HTML e JS

Dessa forma (Não sei se resolveria o seu problema):

```js
var arr_cidades = {
  sp: ["Sorocaba", "Boituva", "Tatuí"],
  rj: ["Uma cidade do Rio", "Outra cidade"]
}

function escolha() {
  var estado = document.querySelector("#estado");
  var cidade = document.querySelector("#cidade");

  cidade.disabled = false;

  cidade.innerHTML = "";

  switch (estado.value) {
    case "sp":
      for (i in arr_cidades.sp) {
        cidade.innerHTML += "<option>" + arr_cidades.sp[i] + "</option>"
      };
      break;
    case "rj":
      for (i in arr_cidades.rj) {
        cidade.innerHTML += "<option>" + arr_cidades.rj[i] + "</option>"
      };
      break;
    default:
      cidade.innerHTML += "<option>- Selecione uma cidade -</option>";
      cidade.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Estado</span>
<br>
<select id='estado' onchange="escolha()">
  <option value=''>- Selecione um Estado -</option>
  <option value='sp'>SP</option>
  <option value='rj'>RJ</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<span>Cidade</span>
<br>
<select id='cidade' disabled="true">
  <option value=''>- Selecione uma Cidade -</option>
    </select>
```

No caso em Var Arr_cidades pode inserir as opções que deseja para cada variação de categoria de produto!

Comment: Quase isso né... Só que ele teria que buscar no banco de dados!

Answer (score 2):

O arquivo de Cardápio você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select onchange="getBebidas()" name="idCardapio" id="idCardapio">
        <option value="0">Selecione o Cardápio</option>
        <!---- Aqui você monta a listagem de todos os ítens do cardápio... todos os tipos. --->
        <option value="1">Cardapio 1</option>
        <option value="2">Cardapio 2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="listaBebidas" id="listaBebidas" class="listaBebidas">
        <option value="0">Primeiro Selecione o Cardápio</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function getBebidas() {
        var id = $('#idCardapio').val();
        $(".listaBebidas").append('<option value="0">Carregando...</option>');
        $.post("cardapio_sql.php?idCardapio=" + id,
            {listaBebidas:jQuery(id).val()},
            function(valor){
                 $(".listaBebidas").html(valor);
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

cardapio_sql.php

```
<!--- Neste arquivo, você faz a conexão com o banco de dados, use o POST['idCardapio'] para pegar o ID do cardápio e faz um SQL com os dados e o while exibindo os resultados apenas em <option> sem precisar do <select> -->
<option>teste</option>
<option>teste2</option>
```

Boa sorte!